# Modular forms of weight $2$ and level $11$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am looking for some books where I can find the determination of the space $M_2(\Gamma _0 (11))$. I know that there is no oldforms in this space. Thus I am interested a way of finding the (I know ther is only one) newforms in $M_2(\Gamma _0 (11))$.

I also know that it might be connected with the study of Hecke operators which I only know that the Hecke operators $T_n$ commute and are codiagonalizables.

Is there a good reference for my question available ? Because I can't find one.

Thank you for helping me,

Comment: I recommend http://people.math.umass.edu/~gunnells/S16/modforms/21.pdf

Comment: A basis over $\mathbf{Q}$ is given by the cuspidal eigenform $f = q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - q^n)^2(1 - q^{11 n})^2 = q - 2 q^2 - 3 q^3 + \ldots $ and the Eisenstein series $E = \frac{5}{12} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^n \left(\sum^{(d,11) = 1}_{d|n} d \right) = \frac{5}{12} + q + 3 q^2 + 4 q^3 + \ldots.$